# upsampling in matlab

Tags: matlab

I try to write a matlab function that upsamples me a picture (matrix of grey values). It is actually nothing overwhelmingly complicated, but I yet manage to do it wrong.
My objective is it to resize it by factor 2 and for the start I just want to see my upscaled picture. I want to fill the gaps with zeros, hence every 2nd row/column is a filled with zeros.
When I am done, I wonder why I see nothing but a grey ocean of pixels. I would have expected to be able to recognize at least some stuff in my picture.

Here is my function, does anyone see my mistake?

```
function [upsampled] = do_my_upsampling(image)
    [X Y] = size(image);
    upsampled = zeros(X*2, Y*2);
    upsampled(1:2:end, 1:2:end) = image(1:1:end, 1:1:end);
end
```

Comment: How are you visualizing the result? Are the sizes of the matrices what you expect? How about the value of `length(find(upsampled==0))`? What have you tried, in other words?

Comment: It is 196608, that seems to work?

Comment: From your question I take it, that you want to recreate this function for some reason. Just in case you are unaware of this: You can umsample an image with the `impyramid()` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code works fine for me (with `image = rand(100);`. However, it's not a very Matlab-way to achieve the result.

If you just want to spread out your pixels, why don't you do direct indexing?

```
[nRows,nCols] = size(image);
upsampled = zeros(2*nRows,2*nCols);
upsampled(1:2:end,1:2:end) = image;
```

Comment: Thx for the hint, I am using your updated version now, but that makes no difference as you already pointed out. 
I am using the Lena picture for my testing. I downsample it (that works, if I display it I see lena in half the size). If I upsample the downsampled picture I am not able to recognize anything.
I checked the index-values, they are there separated by zero rows/colums. I tried it with a low-pass filter, but then my picture becomes a white square....

Answer (score -1):

Try `imshow(image,[])`

or, as your image is a double, convert it into uint8 first and then show i.e

```
imshow(uint8(image))
```