# Inserting variable number of zeros between non-zero elements in a vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, zero

I have a vector like:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6...,n]
```

and I would like to obtain a new vector like this:

```
a_new = [1,0,0,2,0,0,3,0,0,4,0,0,5,0,0,6,...,0,0,n]
```

where a fixed number of zeros (2 in the above example) are inserted between the non-zero elements. If I choose `zero_p=3`, the new vector would be:

```
a_new = [1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,6,...,0,0,0,n]
```

etc.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please see this very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272288/upsampling-in-matlab

Comment: Thank you very much! it was really simple solving it...thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
zero_p=3;
a_new=zeros(1, (zero_p+1)*length(a)-zero_p);
a_new(1:(zero_p+1):end)=a;
```

(Untested, but should hopefully work.)

Answer (score 5):

There's a few ways I can think of:

### Kronecker product

The kronecker product is excellently suited for this. 
In Matlab, `kron` is what you're looking for:

```
a = 1:4;
a = kron(a, [1 0 0])

ans = 

    1     0     0     2     0     0     3     0     0     4     0     0
```

or, generalized,

```
a = 1:4;
zero_p = 3;
b = [1 zeros(1,zero_p-1)];
a = kron(a, b)

ans = 

    1     0     0     2     0     0     3     0     0     4     0     0
```

If you want to have it end with a non-zero element, you have to do one additional step:

```
a = a(1:end-zero_p);
```

Or, if you like one-liners, the whole thing can be done like this:

```
a = 1:4;
zero_p = 3;
a = [kron(a(1:end-1), [1 zeros(1,zero_p-1)]), a(end)]

ans = 

   1     0     0     2     0     0     3     0     0     4
```

### Zero padding

Probably the simplest method and best performance:

```
 a = 1:4;
 zero_p = 3;
 a = [a; zeros(zero_p, size(a, 2))];
 a = a(1:end-zero_p);
```

### Matrix multiplication

Also simple, readable and great performance, although it might be overkill for many situations other than this particular scenario:

```
a = 1:4;
b = [1; zeros(zero_p, 1)];
a = b*a;
a = a(1:end-zero_p);
```

Comment: This is nice, however in the OP's question the new vector ends with a non-zero element.

Answer (score 0):

x = [1 2 3 4 5];
upsample(x,3)

o/p: 1 0 0 2 0 0 3 0 0 4 0 0 5 0 0

Cheers!!

Comment: Format your code (http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting ). Also, if you post an answer that requires a toolbox (in this case, the Signal Processing Toolbox), you should indicate so.